# Minor alignment issue in the activity tab - top tag section

Tags: feature-request, design, activity

In the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) -> Top tag section, the earned reputation placeholder height is differed from the adjacent tag height.

It will be good, if the earned reputation placeholder's height is matching with the tag's height.

> [image: Activity tab - reputation top tag]